# How to get more historical feeds from simplepie?

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

Seems simplepie has a limit of 25 feeds on set_item_limit(). Is there a way to get more historical feeds from simplepie? I know google feed api has a limit of 250, but I cannot easily integrate it in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you link so follow these link and you will get out your solution. It is not limited to just 25 records.

http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie/set_item_limit

http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/how_to_limit_the_number_of_items_displayed_per_feed_when_using_multifeeds.php

Comment: thanks. I tried with several feeds and there's no limit on 25 items. Seems to me that simplepie attempts to return the number of items set in get_items but in the high majority of the cases the items returned are between 10 and 25. There are indeed very very few notable exceptions, as in http://feeds.feedburner.com/longbets returning 161 items or other feeds returning 50. I tried with 300 feeds and a dozen or so return more than 25 items. Could be that simplepie just does not store as much items as for instance google reader? Then why few feeds have more?

Comment: maybe my comment above was not clear. Still does not work. I meant that even though I set a high number of items, just a dozen feeds (I tested more than 300) return more than 25 items (thought those are feeds with hundrens of items). Anybody can tell me why simplepie returns just no more than 25 items in the high majority of feeds? And how canI get more?